# initialize firebase in angular 6 without angularfire

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire

I want had a project that [initialize firebase by using AngularFire](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/building-an-angular-5-project-with-bootstrap-4-and-firebase-4504ff7717c1). However, during the entire development I didn't use much function from AngularFire. I always import the `firebase/app` at every services and use the respective function like `firebase.auth()` or `firebase.database()`.

With that experience, I would like to initialize the firebase without AngularFire since I am not using the AngularFire methods.

Now come with my problem is I can't find any source to teach me how to initialize the firebase, and of course I am seeing error during importing the firebase at `app.module.ts`.

Below is my code:

Install the firebase by using: `npm i firebase`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'; //API key is imported



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase) //here shows the error
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

At the line of `firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase)`, it shows the error:

```
Type 'App' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | 
ModuleWithProviders<any>'.
Type 'App' is not assignable to type 'ModuleWithProviders<any>'.
Property 'ngModule' is missing in type 'App'.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tried doing: `import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';` and `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)` ?

Comment: nope, i want to initialize without angularFire

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say you are having this error because `firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase)` is not Angular Module.

I would suggest that you do this initialisation in one of your services or create a service for that effect.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {
    constructor() {
        firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you cannot import an object which is not an Angular module and you get that error because of that.

You can:
 1. Use it in the AppModule constructor like:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(){         
    firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
  }
}
```

2. Create a dedicated service for Firebase in which you will import 'firebase' lib (which is a good overall solution which will be probably used in your application globally).

```
@Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root' // <-- If you are on Angular 6
    })
    export class FbService {
        constructor() {
            firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);` outside the module and the class, i.e:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);

@NgModule({....
```

If you want to use it inside a service import firebase `import * as firebase from 'firebase';` and use it as usual.