# Angular6 service construction behavior/sequence issue with Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some construction sequence issue that caused my Firebase application doesn't work as expected.

I have a `FirebaseService` to initialize `firebase/app`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {

  firebase:Firebase.app.App
  auth:Firebase.auth.Auth
  firestore:Firebase.firestore.Firestore


  constructor() {
    console.log("hello")
    this.firebase = Firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase,"Angular app");
    console.log(this.firebase.name)//return Angular app
    this.auth = this.firebase.auth()

    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
      console.log(user)
      if(user){
        this.firestore = this.firebase.firestore()
        this.firestore.settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true})

      }
      else{
        this.auth.signInAnonymously().catch(error=>{
         console.log(error)
        })
      }
    })
   }
}
```

Then i imported the FirebaseService into my `app.module.ts` under `providers` array.

Then my `app.component.ts` imported this `FirebaseService` and using the `firestore` method:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../app/services/firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  constructor(private firebase:FirebaseService){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.firebase.firestore.collection("sites").get().then(data=>{
      console.log(data)
    })//return error 
  }
}
```

The Chrome console is returning `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`.

I know the problem is the `AppComponent` code execute before my `signInAnonymously` completed from FirebaseService, but i don't know how to solve it.

I would like to sign user in first before they can use my Firebase services to get data from DB.

My understanding is the angular `service` should fully loaded first, then only goes to component's code, especially the code in `constructor`.

Please advise.

**Edit 1**

Lets say my app.component.ts will need to uid from the onAuthStateChanged before to retrieve data from firestore, how do i make the angular process sequence right?

Answer (score 0):

`firebase` is the name that you are using to reference your `FirebaseService` injected as a dependency in your Component. In this `FirebaseService`, you have your `firebase` property which essentially is your Firebase App Reference.

I think it should be:

```
this.firebase.firebase.firestore.collection("sites").get()
```

in your `ngOnInit`

BTW, I'm not so sure if your Firebase App will initialize synchronously. Since you're using Auth and Firestore from Firebase, you should consider using **[`@angular/fire`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)** which is an Official Angular Module for Firebase for a cleaner implementation.

Comment: if i do it with `this.firebase.firebase.firestore.collection("sites").get()` means i will by pass the user auth checking. My objective is want to ensure the user is signed in before they get to the firebase services. Meanwhile, i the initialize is running synchronously but the `signInAnonymously` might not. I guess i need a solution for the unsynchronous construction issue. I have reason to direct initialize the firebase without angularFire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169685/initialize-firebase-in-angular-6-without-angularfire

Comment: @Jerry, tl;dr; if you use @angular/fire, it would be much easier. In your eg, you're injecting the FirebaseService as a dependency so it would be available even before the user signs in.

Comment: i edited the code by moving the `signInAnonymousely` into the `onAuthStateChanged`. Lets say my `app.component.ts` will need to uid from the `onAuthStateChanged` before retrieving the data from firestore, how do i make the angular process sequence right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which is implement the `onAuthStateChanged` on all other `services.ts` or `component.ts`

Example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../app/services/firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  constructor(private firebase:FirebaseService){
    this.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
      if(user){
        this.firebase.firestore.collection("sites").get().then(data=>{
          data.forEach(ele=>{
            console.log(ele.data())
          })
        })
        //other code to be executed while constructing the page can put here.
      }
    })
  }

}
```